# Input field next to submit button (unknown widths + space)

Tags: css

I am trying to set my form so that it has an input field on the left with a submit button on the right. However, I need the input field to take all the remaining space minus a space of 1rem.

I have tried with this code:

```
<aside class="widget-area">
    <section class="widget-search">
        <form class="search-form">
            <label class="search-label">
                <span class="search-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search..." />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" />
        </form>
    </section>
</aside>

.search-form {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-label {
    display: table-cell;
}

.search-input {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

However, all this does is move the button inside the input field...

I also tried this route:

```
.search-form {
    display: table;
}

.search-label {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

.search-input {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Now the button is next to the input field, but it goes out of the container...

Comment: There's no search-input in your HTML code and the input has no type. Could you please improve your example?

Comment: Consider using a space of 1ch instead of 1rem to separate your input and button. Rems are vertical relative units, while ch are inline relative units, so they make more sense in this context.

Comment: @ragdoll Once 1(r)em is defined as the height of some reference, you can use it for horizontal and/or vertical things. It's a relative unit _defined after a vertical reference_, not particularly a "vertical relative unit".

Comment: Where is your button?

Comment: Ok, I added the input types to improve my example

Comment: @FelipeAls I understand that. I think it's worth considering using the right measurement for the right purpose. Just as you don't use meters to measure an American football field, I think 1ch is more appropriate for horizontal, text-based spacing. It's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Flexbox** on a container so your input will be able to take any remaining space.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/ZOgNjp?editors=1110)** with 2 examples where buttons have different widths and still, input adapt to each situation automagically.

Relevant CSS is:

```
.form-line {
  display: flex;
}
.search-input {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

where the 3 components of flex means: *"can grow, can't shrink, `flex-basis` set to auto"* (somewhat related to a starting width here)

Compatibility: IE9+
Cheat sheet: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Note: I added `for/id` on label/input so that all screen readers can associate them and read out the label to their users

Comment: Your example does exactly what I want to do, however, I can't get it to work with the font size

Comment: Ok, so after playing with the code for a while, it seems that by adding min-width: 0 and width: 100% to my search field, it works even with the font-size now. I also had to set the shrink property to 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like that?

```css
.search-form {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-label {
   float: left;
  width:200px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.search-submit {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<aside class="widget-area">
    <section class="widget-search">
        <form class="search-form">
            <label class="search-label">Hello</label>
            <input class="search-submit" />
        </form>
    </section>
</aside>
```

Comment: What if label is as short as "Name" or is longer in your german/finnish/french translation than the original english label? A width of 200px is an assumption you don't need to have (and I'd rather not if I can avoid it)

Comment: yes if you want it dynamic you have to calculate it with jquery or read into flexbox